# New error on random number assigned to local variable , Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, random

I'm experimenting with some Bootstrap tabs that render partials, and inside the partials are other nested tabs that could possibly eventually render the same partials, in a never ending maze of Bootstrap tabs. I resolved the issue of certain tabs not working within the maze (because their divs were using the same ID assigned to previous partials) by assigning a random number each time a partial is rendered, and putting the random number as part of the partial's div IDs.

```
<% asdf = rand(1000000000) %>
<div class="<% order.id %>_<%= @menu.order_type %>_<%= asdf %>">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#<%= order.id %>_<%= @menu.order_type %>_qwer_general_info_<%= asdf %>"><%= order.qwer_zxcv_name.upcase %>General</a></li>
etc.
```

However, this morning I woke up and I'm getting
`Error: No most-recent exception` when it assigns a random number to asdf.

I can assign a random number to any other local variable, just not 'asdf' (for the record the local variable in the code is 'wtf').

I researched the error, and Google does not show anything conclusive.

I'm pretty curious as to why this error is appearing today when it was all working perfectly yesterday, if anybody has a hint.

Comment: I am assuming you are also using `pry`? `pry` includes a [`WTFcommand`](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/master/lib/pry/commands/wtf.rb) which is documented as *"Print the stack trace, same as _ex_.backtrace"*. I am unclear on what this means *"However, this morning I woke up and I'm getting `Error: No most-recent exception` when it assigns a random number to asdf."*, unless you mean when debugging (e.g. `binding.pry`) I type `wtf` and I get "`Error: No most-recent exception`", in which case yes that is reproducible.

Comment: `pry` will recognize `wtf` as a command prior to trying to evaluate it as a local variable; however you should be able to see that the local variable is assigned correctly using `binding.local_variable_get('wtf')`. Other than that the error you are reporting (if there is one) is very unclear. Also had you not added *"for the record the local variable in the code is 'wtf'"* there would have been no way to help, which is why obfuscation is not generally a good idea other than to hide sensitive information.

Comment: Noted thank you. It did occur to me that ```wtf``` was a special word, but dismissed it. I was debugging in ```pry``` and ```local_variable_get('wtf')``` does show the correctly assigned variable. I switched the variable names because I'm ashamedly amateur, but if ```pry``` uses then I'm redeemed. So something else new is causing my perfect tabs to fail today then. Thank you

Comment: For a unique identifier, consider using [UUIDv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) (Universally Unique IDentifier version 4). It is, essentially, a random number, but a much larger one with less chance of collision (see the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for why collisions are more likely than you think) and an accepted standard.

Comment: Nice, will do, ty

Comment: For the record, UUIDv4 was achieved in Rails using ```SecureRandom.uuid```, as in ```wtf = SecureRandom.uuid```